# How to correct the sql query to execute in python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have one SQL query which I have to execute through python.
I have made connection with MYSQL but query format is not up to the mark.

Can you please help me to convert query in correct format for python.

query:

```
select trim(CONCAT_WS('|',"Master Job Name","Seq","TableName","Source File Name Lnd","landingdfname","TargetPath","query1","Execution Sequence")) FROM DUAL
```

i ran the code-

```
with db.cursor() as cur:
    query_meta = ("select trim(CONCAT_WS('|',Master Job Name,Seq,TableName,Source File Name Lnd,landingdfname,TargetPath,query1,Execution Sequence)) FROM DUAL")
    res = cur.execute(query_meta)
    res = cur.fetchall()
```

error -

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name,Seq,TableName,Source File Name Lnd,landingdfname,TargetPath,query1,Executio' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
cursor.execute("select trim(CONCAT_WS('|','Master Job Name','Seq','TableName','Source File Name Lnd','landingdfname','TargetPath','query1','Execution Sequence')) FROM DUAL")
```

Query format is this:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(',', input_string1, input_string2,...)
FROM 
    table_name
```

Comment: No, still it is not working. Problem is coming in query format.

Comment: "Source File Name Lnd" and "Execution Sequence" Check this parameter. It should not have space and still if you have hard coded it, put it in ' ' this quotes

Comment: Hi @vaibhav Jadhav, I need one help also.

Comment: I am getting output from the above query like this - [{u"trim(CONCAT_WS('|','Master Job Name','Seq','TableName','Source File Name Lnd','landingdfname','TargetPath','query1','Execution Sequence'))": 'Master Job Name|Seq|TableName|Source File Name Lnd|landingdfname|TargetPath|query1|Execution Sequence'}]

Comment: I want output like this only : Master Job Name|Seq|TableName|Source File Name Lnd|landingdfname|TargetPath|query1|Execution Sequence

Comment: @jay .I have commented on your new question thread related to this.

Comment: hi @vaibhav Jadhav can you update the below query :

Comment: query_meta1 = ("SELECT trim(CONCAT_WS('|',mtd.Master_Job_Name,Seq,Table_Name,Source_File_Name_Lnd,landingdfname,Target_Path,query,mtd.Execution_Sequence  )) from imedical_master_metadata mtd inner join imedical_master_metadata_query mtq on (mtd.Master_Job_Name=mtq.Master_Job_Name) where mtd.Is_Active='Y' order by mtd.Execution_Sequence")

Comment: Yup sure. Let me see

Comment: @jay The columns"Seq,Table_Name,Source_File_Name_Lnd,landingdfname,Target_Path,query" are to be taken from which table

Comment: Try this: query_meta1 = ("SELECT trim(CONCAT_WS('|',mtd.Master_Job_Name,mtd.Seq,mtd.Table_Name,mtd.Source_mtd.File_Name_mtd.Lnd,landingdfname,mtd.Target_Path,mtd.query,mtd.Execution_Sequence )) from imedical_master_metadata mtd inner join imedical_master_metadata_query mtq on (mtd.Master_Job_Name=mtq.Master_Job_Name) where mtd.Is_Active='Y' order by mtd.Execution_Sequence")